# flutter how to get a circular progress indicator working

Tags: dart, flutter

***UPDATE***
I have changed to use a widget and put all the code for the Stateful Widget below.

There is lots of code to this, I changed to use a stack with a Widget loadingIndicator, but it still does not get called.  My stack is around a future response, with the indicator at the bottom, I then use the onPress from a button click to call a method that changes state and then I call the other process to run.  Still nothing happens with the indicator.

```
class ChatServerDivided extends StatefulWidget {
  ChatServerDivided({Key key, this.title, this.mychat}) : super(key: key);

  static const String routeName = "/ChatServerDivided";

  final ChatServerList mychat;
  final String title;

  @override
  _ChatServerDividedState createState() => new _ChatServerDividedState();
}

class _ChatServerDividedState extends State<ChatServerDivided> {
  SharedPreferences prefs;
  int oid = 0;
  int pid = 0;
  int authlevel = 0;
  bool admin = false;
  int type = 0;
  String msgid = '';
  List chatlist;
  int listcount = 0;
  bool grpmsg = true;
  String sender = '';
  String receiver = '';
  String message = '';
  String oname = '';
  String pname = '';
  String sendname;
  String receivename;
  String replyto = '';
  String replyfrom = '';
  String replysub = '';
  final TextEditingController _newreplycontroller = new TextEditingController();
  String myfcmtoken = 'NONE';
  static ScrollController _scrollController;
  bool messSync = false;

  //Future<http.Response> _responseFuture;
  Future<List<Map>> _responseFuture;
  var _urlDates = '';
  Future<File> _imageFile;
  String myimage;
  String myvideo;
  File myimagefile;
  File myvidfile;
  Future<int> myimagelength;
  String myext;
  VideoPlayerController vcontroller;
  bool isImage = false;
  bool isVideo = false;
  bool submitting = false;

  //ScrollController scontroller = new ScrollController();

  _getPrefs() async {
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        oid = prefs.getInt('oid');
        pid = prefs.getInt('pid');
        authlevel = prefs.getInt('authlevel');
        admin = prefs.getBool('admin');
        type = 1;
        msgid = widget.mychat.msgkey;
        if (widget.mychat.grpid == 0) {
          grpmsg = false;
        } else {
          grpmsg = true;
        }
        oname = widget.mychat.oname;
        pname = widget.mychat.pname;
        myfcmtoken = prefs.getString('fcmtoken');
        if (authlevel == 0) {
          sender = 'o';
          receiver = 'p';
          sendname = widget.mychat.oname;
          receivename = widget.mychat.pname;
        } else if (authlevel == 1) {
          sender = 'p';
          receiver = 'o';
          sendname = widget.mychat.pname;
          receivename = widget.mychat.oname;
        }
        //_getChats();
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //controller = new TabController(length: 4, vsync: this);

    _scrollController = new ScrollController();
    //_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent;
    _getPrefs();
    _urlDates =
        'http://$baseurl/chat/messages/getdates/${widget
        .mychat.msgkey}';
    _responseFuture = ChatDB.instance.getMessagesDates(widget.mychat.msgkey);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    if (vcontroller != null) {
      vcontroller.dispose();
    }

  }

  var jsonCodec = const JsonCodec();
  var _focusnode = new FocusNode();

  _getChats() async {
    var _url =
        'http://$baseurl/chat/messages/getdates/$msgid';

    var http = createHttpClient();
    var response = await http.get(_url, headers: getAuthHeader());

    var chats = await jsonCodec.decode(response.body);

    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        chatlist = chats.toList();
        listcount = chatlist.length;
        //replysub = 'Re: ' + chatlist[0]['sub'];
      });
    }
  }

  Future<Null> _onRefresh() {
    Completer<Null> completer = new Completer<Null>();
    Timer timer = new Timer(new Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      setState(() {
        _responseFuture =
            ChatDB.instance.getMessagesDates(widget.mychat.msgkey);
        print('RUNNING LOAD AFTER REFRESH AGAIN');
      });
      completer.complete();
    });
    return completer.future;
  }

  Future<String> doImageString() async {
    return (await _imageFile)
        .path
        .substring((await _imageFile).path.length - 3);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _toggleProgress() {
      setState(() {
        submitting = true;
      });

    };
    Widget loadingIndicator =submitting? new Container(
      color: Colors.grey[300],
      width: 70.0,
      height: 70.0,
      child: new Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),child: new Center(child: new CircularProgressIndicator())),
    ):new Container();
    Widget mytitle;
    if (grpmsg) {
      mytitle = new Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Icon(Icons.people),
          new Text('  '),
          new Text(widget.mychat.referralname)
        ],
      );
    } else {
      mytitle = new Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Icon(Icons.person),
          new Text('  '),
          new Text(widget.mychat.referralname)
        ],
      );
    }

    var _children = <Widget>[
      new Flexible(
        child: new Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            new FutureBuilder<List<Map>>(
              future: _responseFuture,
              builder:
                  (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Map>> snapshot) {
                switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                  case ConnectionState.none:
                    return new Text('Waiting to start');
                  case ConnectionState.waiting:
                    return new Text('Loading...');
                  default:
                    if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                    } else {
                      return new RefreshIndicator(
                          child: new ListView.builder(
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return new MyChatWidget(
                                datediv: snapshot.data[index]['msgdate'],
                                msgkey: snapshot.data[index]['msgkey'],
                              );

                            },
                            //itemBuilder: _itemBuilder,
                            controller: _scrollController,
                            reverse: true,
                            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                          ),
                          onRefresh: _onRefresh
                      );
                    }
                }
              },
            ),
            new Align(child: loadingIndicator,alignment: FractionalOffset.center,),
          ],
        ),
      ),

      new Container(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
          padding: new EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
          child: new FutureBuilder<File>(
              future: _imageFile,
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<File> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                  //return new Image.file(snapshot.data);
                  myimagefile = snapshot.data;
                  myext = path.extension(myimagefile.path);
                  if (myext == '.jpg') {
                    isImage = true;
                    return new Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new Container(
                          alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                          width: 150.0,
                          child: new Image.file(snapshot.data),
                        ),
                        new FlatButton(
                            onPressed: _doClear,
                            child: new Text('Clear Image'))
                      ],
                    );
                  } else {
                    isVideo = true;
                    myvidfile = new File(
                        snapshot.data.path.replaceAll('file://', ''));
                    vcontroller = new VideoPlayerController(myimagefile.path)..initialize();
                    return new Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new Container(
                          alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                          width: 150.0,
                          child: new vplayer.VideoCard(
                            controller: vcontroller,
                            title: widget.mychat.referralname,
                            subtitle: 'Video',
                          ),
                        ),
                        new FlatButton(
                            onPressed: _doClear,
                            child: new Text('Clear Video'))
                      ],
                    );
                  }
                } else {
                  return const Text('');
                }
              })
      ),

      new Divider(
        height: 5.0,
        color: Colors.grey,
      ),
      new Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Container(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            //width: 50.0,
            child: new IconButton(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.add_a_photo),
              onPressed: _pickImage,
              alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            ),
          ),
          new Flexible(
            child: new Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              //width: 350.0,
              child: new TextField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Reply',
                  labelText: 'Reply:',
                ),
                autofocus: false,
                focusNode: _focusnode,
                maxLines: 1,
                controller: _newreplycontroller,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          new Container(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
              //width: 50.0,
              child: new IconButton(
                icon: new Icon(Icons.send),
                onPressed: () {
                  _toggleProgress();
                  _sendReply();
                },
                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                disabledColor: Colors.grey,
              )),
        ],
      ),
    ];

    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: mytitle,
        actions: getAppBarActions(context),
      ),
      body: new Column(
        children: _children,
      ),
    );
  }

  DateTime getDateDiv(int index) {
    DateTime msgdate = DateTime.parse(chatlist[index]['chatdate']).toLocal();
    return msgdate;
  }

  _doClear() {
    setState(() {
      _imageFile = null;
    });
  }

  _pickImage() async {
    await setState(() {
      _imageFile = ImagePicker.pickImage(maxWidth: 600.0);
    });
  }

  _sendReply() {
    if (_newreplycontroller.text.isEmpty && myimagefile == null) {
      /*showDialog(
        context: context,
        child: new AlertDialog(
          content: new Text("There is no message to submit"),
          actions: <Widget>[
            new FlatButton(
                child: const Text('OK'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context, false);
                }),
          ],
        ),
      );*/
    } else {

      TextInputAction.done;
      DateTime dateSubmit = new DateTime.now();
      if (myimagefile != null) {
        if (isImage) {
          List<int> imageBytes = myimagefile.readAsBytesSync();
          myimage = BASE64.encode(imageBytes);
          myvideo = 'NONE';
        }
        if (isVideo) {
          List<int> imageBytes = myvidfile.readAsBytesSync();
          myvideo = BASE64.encode(imageBytes);
          myimage = 'NONE';
        }
      } else {
        myimage = 'NONE';
        myvideo = 'NONE';
      }
      var mymessage = _newreplycontroller.text;
      ChatServerMessage mychat = new ChatServerMessage(
          widget.mychat.msgkey,
          'message',
          widget.mychat.refid,
          widget.mychat.referralname,
          replysub,
          oid,
          oname,
          pid,
          pname,
          sender,
          sendname,
          receiver,
          receivename,
          mymessage,
          dateSubmit.toString(),
          widget.mychat.grpid.toString(),
          widget.mychat.prid.toString(),
          myfcmtoken,
          myimage,
          myvideo,
          myext);
      _doSendReply(mychat);
    }
  }


  _doSendReply(mychat) async {
    var json = jsonCodec.encode(mychat);
    ChatConnect.instance.sendmessage(json);
    _checkSync () {
      messSync = ChatConnect.instance.isSynced;
      if (messSync) {
        if (isImage) {
          Timer synctimer = new Timer(new Duration(seconds: 2), _checkSync);
        } else if (isVideo) {
          Timer synctimer = new Timer(new Duration(seconds: 5), _checkSync);
        } else {
          Timer synctimer = new Timer(new Duration(seconds: 2), _checkSync);
        }

      } else {
        setState(() {

          submitting = false;
          _onRefresh();
          _doClear();
          print('RUNNING LOAD AFTER SEND AGAIN');
        });
        _newreplycontroller.text = '';
        _focusnode.unfocus();
      }
    }
    _checkSync();

  }
}
```

Comment: Please share the whole code

Comment: The flutter docs itself has an example of implementing progress indicator and you can take a look at it [here](https://flutter.io/flutter-for-android/#how-do-i-show-progress-indicator-in-flutter-when-there-is-a-task-that-is-running).

Hope that is what you were looking for.

Comment: I have put the code from the stateful widget that does the work, any help would be great.

Comment: Every library and framework I use the circular progress spinner is the only widget/component/uiview broken in some weird way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had Created a example based on your query

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

 void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(home: new sample()));
  }


class sample extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_sampleState createState() => new _sampleState();
}

class _sampleState extends State<sample> {

bool _progressBarActive = true;
 @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new Scaffold(
  appBar:new AppBar(
    title: new Text("Circular progressbar demo"),
  ),
body: _progressBarActive == true?const CircularProgressIndicator():new Container());
}
}
```

Comment: the new Container has collapsed?

Answer (score 5):

I created an example based on your code snippet above. Black app with an button to toggle the submitting value using setState(). 
Tapping the FloatingActionButton calls setState, toggling the value of submitting. And the progress indicator is shown.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(home: new SubmitPage()));
}

class SubmitPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SubmitPageState createState() => new _SubmitPageState();
}

class _SubmitPageState extends State<SubmitPage> {
  bool submitting = false;

  void toggleSubmitState() {
    setState(() {
      submitting = !submitting;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Center(
        child: !submitting
            ? new Container(
                color: Colors.grey,
              )
            : const Center(child: const CircularProgressIndicator()),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        child: new Icon(Icons.refresh),
        onPressed: toggleSubmitState,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you use .gif image instead?

Simply place your gif in your images folder of your project and mention it in pubspec.yaml file,just like you do for images.

```
Image(
    image: AssetImage('images/circular-progress-bar.gif'),
    width: 40,
    height:40
 );
```

Comment: gifs are inefficient and huge if wanted to look good (e.g. 60fps). also why use gif that cannot be customized if flutter provides a widget for that kind of a task?