# Show CircularProgressIndicator in front in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to display a circular bar like loading in front of other widgets. 
Below is the code which i am currently using. It shows the Circular loading but its between other widget.

It should be on top. Based on the suggestion I tried using Stack but it is still showing in between the widget. What am I doing wrong here?

```
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();

}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {

 bool visible = true ; //Testing purpose it is true. Actually it is false.    
@override

Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return Scaffold(
  key: _scaffoldKey,
  body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topRight,
              end: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,//Alignment.bottomLeft,

              colors: [Colors.green[900], Colors.lightBlueAccent]),
        ),

          ),SingleChildScrollView(
            child: new Form(
              key: _formKey,
              autovalidate: _autoValidate,
    child: Center(
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    VerticalText(),
                    TextLogin(),                    
                  ],
                ),


        Divider(),          

        Container(
        width: 280,

        ),
        Container(
        width: 280,
        child: TextFormField(
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: InputBorder.none,
            hintText: 'Enter Email',
            fillColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            labelText: 'Email',
            labelStyle: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white70,
              fontSize: 20,
            ),
            ),
            controller: emailController,
            autocorrect: true,
            validator: validateEmail,
            onSaved: (String val) {
              _email = val;
          },
          )
        ),

        Container(
        width: 280,
        child: TextFormField(
             style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: InputBorder.none,
            hintText: 'Enter Password',
            fillColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            labelText: 'Password',
            labelStyle: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white70,
              fontSize: 20,
            ),
            ),
            controller: passwordController,
            autocorrect: true,
            obscureText: true,
            validator: validatePassword,
              onSaved: (String val) {
                _password = val;
          },
          )
        ),

        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: _validateInputs,
          color: Colors.green,
          textColor: Colors.white,
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
          child: Text('Login'),
        ),


        Visibility(
          child: Center(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  strokeWidth: 4.0,
                  valueColor : AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.white),
                ),
                height: 200.0,
                width: 200.0,
              ),

            ],
          ),
        ),
          visible: visible, 
      ),
      ],
    ),
  )
            )
  )
        ],
),
);
}
```

I have seen similar questions in SO but still getting hard time to resolve it.

[How to work with progress indicator in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47065098/how-to-work-with-progress-indicator-in-flutter)

[flutter how to get a circular progress indicator working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48493319/flutter-how-to-get-a-circular-progress-indicator-working)

[Flutter : create an overlay progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58277766/flutter-create-an-overlay-progress-bar)

[How to display CircularProgressIndicator on top of all widget in a centre of the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51952927/how-to-display-circularprogressindicator-on-top-of-all-widget-in-a-centre-of-the)

Comment: I got it working. Actually i need to place it before the last widget. I will put my answer

Comment: Have you checked my solution?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The real meaning of circularProgressIndicator is to be run while loading process without letting user interrupt.
To remove interruption by user in between, one should put circularProgressIndicator in a dialog with property `barrierDismissible: false`.
One should create this loading indicator as reusable widget.
You can craete a method like below and can use it anywhere over the screen without defining in screen. (this does not require stack also.). Dialog will appear on the center of the screen.

```
buildShowDialog(BuildContext context) {
    return showDialog(
              context: context,
              barrierDismissible: false,
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              });
  }
```

**For Reference**: Checkout code below:

```
void main() => runApp(App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Demo(),
    );
  }
}

class Demo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Circle Progress Indicator Demo"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: MaterialButton(
          child: Text("Press Me!"),
          onPressed: () => buildShowDialog(context),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  buildShowDialog(BuildContext context) {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: how can i show a text under this circularprogressindicator, i tried to put a column with the circularprogressindicator and the text but the text is showing in a weird way

Comment: I know this is old and will probably be ignored, but will still try: what makes the progress indicator disappear after a while? why doesn't it just stay in view?

Comment: @RuiAlves Indicator will stay. The above gif continuously running which let you think so. Implementing in snippet will clear your doubts.

Comment: oh I see, thank you @SanketVekariya I understand now.

Answer (score 11):

Like said, the real meaning of `CircularProgressIndicator` is to be run while loading a process without letting user interrupt.
Create this loading indicator as a reusable .dart file.
With this you can use the LoadingIndicator flexible everywhere and overlay the current screen.

You just have to make a .dart file containing:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

buildLoading(BuildContext context) {
  return showDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
            valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.blue),
          ),
        );
      });
}
```

Then you can use it anywhere using

```
buildLoading(context);
```

and dismiss it when loading is done using

```
Navigator.of(context).pop();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Positioned` Widget in `Stack` Widget for Showing `CircularProgressIndicator` in front of all widgets like below..
Please put values according to your convenience in all four values bottom,left,right,top...

```
         Positioned(
                bottom: ,
                left: ,
                right: , 
                top : ,
                child: Container(
                        child : CircularProgressIndicator()
                      )
                    ...
                   )
```

Comment: Thanks Jaimil. I will test and confirm. Voted up.

Comment: Getting erorr. Positioned widgets must be placed directly inside Stack widgets.

Comment: Yeah you should place positioned widget in stack

Comment: If it resolve your issue then please accept my answer then other user can get benefit from it

Answer (score 1):

I removed `Visiblity` code with this one.
    **Old Code**

```
 Visibility(

          child: Center(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  strokeWidth: 4.0,
                  valueColor : AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.white),
                ),
                height: 200.0,
                width: 200.0,
              ),


            ],
          ),
        ),
          visible: visible, 
      ),
```

**New Code**

```
 visible ? Container(
                        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                        child:  Center(
                        child:SizedBox(// Center(

                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                            strokeWidth: 4.0,
                      valueColor : AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.white),
                          ),
                          height: 200.0,
                          width: 200.0,
                        ),
                       ), 
    )
                      : Container()
```

And most importantly it needs to call in the first Widget.

```
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
/////Some containers,child Widget etc/////////
     visible ? Container(
                            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                            child:  Center(
                            child:SizedBox(// Center(

                              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                strokeWidth: 4.0,
                          valueColor : AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.white),
                              ),
                              height: 200.0,
                              width: 200.0,
                            ),
                           ), 
        )
                          : Container()

] //Widget
  ), //Stack
); //Scaffold
```

I am not sure i explained it properly or not. But Bottom line is it shouldn't be inside the other child widget. 
It should be placed inside first `children: <Widget>[` not inside the nested.

Answer (score 1):

As above most of them gave answer to make separate reusable function. So here is mine if you want to fetch some data and display circular progress indicator while data is being fetched.

```
///Function to get data from a future and display a dialog with circlular progress indicator while data is fetched.
getFutureData(BuildContext context, var future) async {
  var data;
  await showDialog(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false,
    builder: (context) => Center(
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: future,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            data = snapshot.data;
            Navigator.pop(context);
          }
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        },
      ),
    ),
  );
  return data;
}
```